can't install mysql-connector with my pip
I'm trying to install mysql connector using pip but it keeps showing me this error:
connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', TimeoutError('timed out'))': /simple/mysqlx-connector/

I think it could be a result of filtering in my region


Welcome to SO! Also please copy paste your code. Please do not post images of your code.

It should be
pip install mysql-connector-python

Link to the pypi: https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/



The latter error in the image shows a ProxyError for a different package
